# SingleChoiceDialog is not showing in Top-level frame

Tags: python, wxpython

I have written code for SingleChoiceDialog in Wxpython as

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "My Choose_List Frame", size =(300,300))

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self,-1)

        self.choose_list = wx.SingleChoiceDialog(self.panel,'Wt things u want do in u r life?','single Choice', ['Eating','Drinking', 'Working'])
        if self.choose_list == wx.ID_OK:
            resp = self.choose_list.GetSelections()
            print resp


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

But in the Top-Level frame, SingleChoiceDialog is not showing.

Can Anyone Help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to `Show()`/`ShowModal()` the dialog.
I have also changed the selection.
I single choice will not have a `GetSelections()` method.
It will have a `GetSelection()` but that simply returns the index of the choice.
Instead, run with the `GetStringSelection()`, which will of course always return "Drinking", only joking ;)

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "My Choose_List Frame", size =(300,300))

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self,-1)

        self.choose_list = wx.SingleChoiceDialog(self.panel,'Wt things u want do in u r life?','single Choice', ['Eating','Drinking', 'Working'])

        if self.choose_list.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            resp = self.choose_list.GetStringSelection()
            print resp


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks, @Rolf of Saxony